# How to remove element from one object and move it to another one?

Tags: javascript

So I have this array

```
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    items: {
      '1': {
        name: 'apple',
        id: '1',
        parent: {
          id: 1
        }
      },
      '2': {
        name: 'orange',
        id: '2',
        parent: {
          id: 2
        }
      },
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    items: {
      '3': {
        name: 'banana',
        id: '3',
        parent: {
          id: 3
        }
      },
    }
  },
]
```

What I want to do is to move any item from one `items` subobject to antoher.

So far I figure out how to delete item from the source object and updating this item with the data about the new "parent".

```
const moveObjects = (element, itemId) => {
      const newElements = array.map(el => {
        const elsIds = Object.keys(el.items);
    
    
        elsIds.forEach(id => {
          if (id == itemId) {
            const tempItem = el.items[itemId];
            tempItem.parent = {
              id: element.id,
            };
            delete el.items[itemId];
          }
        });
        return el;
      });
    
      return newElements;
    }

const elementToMoveTo = {
  id: 2,
  ...
}

console.log(moveObjects(elementToMoveTo, 1))
```

And right now I am struggling with how to update the destination object with this `tempItem`.
Maybe there should be different approach to do this.

All the help will be appreciated.
[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5Lhqyo1/)

The result from code above should be

```
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    items: {
      '2': {
        name: 'orange',
        id: '2',
        parent: {
          id: 2
        }
      },
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    items: {

      '1': {
        name: 'apple',
        id: '1',
        parent: {
          id: 2
        }
      },
      '3': {
        name: 'banana',
        id: '3',
        parent: {
          id: 3
        }
      },
    }
  },
]
```

Comment: Can you show us what the desired result should be.

Comment: What about parent: {id: 1} must it be also changed to new parent id? In case of apple to be 2?

Comment: @ArthurRubens yes, sorry, you are right

Answer (score -1):

This works! I have tried and tested it. Donot get confused with the && thing, it is basically just to check if the previous value is null/undefined (basically any value that returns a falsy value)

```
    let theItemKey = "3";
    let fromObj = 1;
    let toObj = 0;
    let theItem = array && 
                    array[fromObj] && 
                      array[fromObj].items && 
                        array[fromObj].items[theItemKey];
    array[toObj].items[theItemKey] = theItem;
    delete array[fromObj].items[theItemKey];
```

Answer (score -1):

If I were you I would code like this:

```js
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    items: {
      '1': {
        name: 'apple',
        id: '1',
        parent: {
          id: 1
        }
      },
      '2': {
        name: 'orange',
        id: '2',
        parent: {
          id: 2
        }
      },
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    items: {
      '3': {
        name: 'banana',
        id: '3',
        parent: {
          id: 3
        }
      },
    }
  },
]


const moveObjects = (elementId, itemId) => {

  //creates a new array from existed one
  let newArray = [...array];

  //finds an element where I should move the item
  let element = newArray.find(el => el.id === elementId);
  let item = null;

  //if element is found -> continue
  if (element) {
  
    newArray.forEach(el => {
    
      //if the item is a property of an element.items -> copies the founded item to the variable "item" then delete the property from the previous parent 

      if (el.items[itemId]) {
        el.items[itemId].parent.id = itemId;
        item = el.items[itemId];

        delete el.items[itemId];
      }
    });
    
    //adds item to a new parent
    element.items[itemId] = item;
  }

  //returns a new array 
  return newArray;
}

console.log(moveObjects(2, "1"))
```